# scrollTop() -> Type error undefined n.easing

Tags: jquery, typeerror, easing

The following script is working live for 2 times. The third time i click on a a with a hash it does not work any more and the following error shows up in the Console. Any ideas?

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'n.easing[this.easing](a,this.options.duration*a,0,1,this.options.duration)')
```

[Screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/0H2R3P3B0F03): [image]

My Code:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTo: target.offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  }
}  });

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 220) {
    $('.backtotop').fadeIn(200);
} else {
    $('.backtotop').fadeOut(200);
}});
```

Code from the html:

```
<a href="#link">LINK</a>
<div id="link">TARGET</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What looks like the target ?

Comment: <a href="#link">LINK</a>

Target: 
<div id="link">LINK TARGET</div>

Comment: @max please avoid adding code in comments. update information in the question rather than comments so that it'll get more attention...

Comment: You've got jQueryUI included?

Comment: no i did not. :) any way to not include jQueryUi and change the code instead?

Comment: The problem is somewhere else in your page. I can't get any errors in the console: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y3Vx/

Comment: @max try changing `scrollTo` to `scrollTop` =) (Within the animate)

Answer (score 0):

There has been a different error in the code. 
I am very sorry :) 
I have a slider, which does not work. Superslides BTW. After 4 seconds the error above appears.